# How to fix "Cant play this video" error in Camera MX Live Shots after upgrade?

Tags: ota-update, video

I use a Galaxy Note 4.  To get 'live shots', a few months ago I downloaded the app Camera MX.  I just received an OTA update to Marshmallow, and now every time I try to view live shots created before the update I get the error: "Can't play this video".

So far, I've found that the app stores the video clip that comprises the 'live shot' as a standard .mp4 video clip in a hidden folder '.LiveShot'.  I've tried to find some sort of file that maps the .jpg pictures to the corresponding .mp4 in the .LiveShot folder, but I can't seem to find anything.  I even used exiftool on the .jpg files to see if it was embedded somehow, but exiftool doesn't see it.  Is there some sort of fix out there for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After using exiftool I went one level deeper and just opened one of the .jpg files with a hex editor.  Turns out the path to the 'live shot' is indeed embedded in the .jpg file, just not as EXIF data (or at least not standard EXIF data that exiftool can read).  I put my SD card into my linux laptop and tried using the following sed command to fix them:

```
sed -i 's/\/storage\/extSdCard\/Android\/media\/com\.magix\.camera_mx\/Camera MX (SD)\/\.LiveShot/\/storage\/3F25-4093\/Android\/media\/com\.magix\.camera_mx\/Camera MX (SD)\/\.LiveShot/g' *.jpg
```

This worked for some of the files, but others (with even older paths such as /storage/emulated/0) simply became corrupt afterward.  If anyone knows of a better fix I'd love to hear it.